# Changing table for select statement based on dropdown with ajax function?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I am trying to setup a table on my site that is populated based on the users selection of from a drop down menu. The dropdown menu should make up the variables that will perform the SELECT statement.
To do this I have a HTML drop down and a AJAX function. This the function ...

```
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("loadhere").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("loadhere").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxtest.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

And this is the HTML

```
<form action="">
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Please choose</option>
<option value="1200">Courses</option>
<option value="">TEST</option>
<option value="">TEST</option>
<option value="">TEST</option>
</select>
</form>     
<br>
<div id="loadhere"><b>Details will be listed here after selection.</b></div>
```

This then calls a php script

```
$q=$_GET["q"];


$sql="SELECT * FROM clntcoursetbl WHERE mbrid = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table id='box-table-b'>
<tr>
<th>Course</th>
<th>Start Date</th>
<th>Finish Date</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['course'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['startdate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['finishdate'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";


?>
```

Currently I have a value of 1200 against the select option of 'course' , this is the client ID of the user and was just for testing to make sure everything works. Which it does.

Now , I would like to change it so that the value in the select is put into the SELECT statement to choose the table to search.
Something along the lines of "SELECT * FROM **selected value** WHERE mbrid = '".$q."'";

Is this possible ?

If so, how can I can I then also make the mbrid dynamic ? Can I pass a session variable into the function perhaps ??

As always , thanks for you help !

Comment: 1. stop using `mysql_*` functions, use PDO or MySQLi instead; 2. suggest to use libraries such as jQuery to handle AJAX requests (for better cross-browser compatibility); 3. suggest to use single quotes in plain PHP strings to reduce extra parsing time.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an ajax call in the `showUser()` function which can go like this.

```
var url = "url of the file you want to get data from"; 
var e = document.getElementById("#<Your Select Items ID>"); 
var data = 'q='+e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
         $.ajax({
             type: "post",
             url: url,
             data: data,
             success: function(msg) {
             }
         });
```

Then you can use $_POST['q'] to get the value in your destination page.

Also try appending all your echo data to a variable and do an echo when you loop execution is complete.

Comment: But can I change the table name in my select statement ? SELECT * FROM tablename , I need to be able to change the table name, each option on the dropdown will represent a different table

Comment: yes you can, just send the table name along with the ajax `data`. you can append using `data += '&tableName='+<your table name variable>;` and then receive it in your post along with the data 'q' as `$tableName = $_POST['tableName'];`. and use it in your sql statement as `$sql="SELECT * FROM '".$tableName."' WHERE mbrid = '".$q."'";`